# Why on navigation build method is called for all widgets with route arguments, even invisible ones?

Tags: flutter, navigation

Suppose there is a widget extracting navigator arguments inside its build method by calling `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments`.

Its build method is called, when I am navigating to it, which is normal. But what I noticed is that its build method gets called when I am popping from this widget.

Even more, when there is a chain of widgets, passing route arguments to each other, when navigating between them either through push or pop, build methods of ALL of them fire up, even though they are not visible.

Is this by design? What is the reason for such behavior? For me it currently causes extra trips to database.

Comment: yes, this is by design - you cannot avoid that

Comment: @pskink Any reasons for such design?

Comment: Why does it have to be up to date if it is hidden? besides, this happens not only to parent and not only on popping. Whole hierarchy is involved when navigating.

Comment: your `build` method must be designed so that it has no side effects - basically `build` method can be called by a framework multiple times and you have to be prepared for this

Comment: I have FutureBuilder in my build method, and it does a roundtrip to database on each call. Besides, framework can call it whenever it wants, I just need to know the reason.

Comment: if you really want to know the details why this happen study `Overlay` / `OverlayState` class sources which are the working horses in navigating stuff, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart